# Multisite - Cloning CPT pages + content (including ACF Flexible Content) from site to site

Tags: plugins, multisite, advanced-custom-fields, content, post-duplication

I wondered if anyone had any WordPress Multisite knowledge where I need to be able to move pages and content from one site to another?

A little bit of background, I've done this previously using the 'Multisite Post Duplicator
' plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/) however this plugin hasn't been updated in 3 years and i'm not sure whether this will do the job now that the core would have been updated many versions since then.

I've looked at a number of plugins and some that I come across state that content can be copied over and mention ACF (which is important) however they state they won't copy over repeater/flexible content which is imperative.

I'm more than happy with purchasing a plugin that will do the job I require but as I mention, all of my research comes up with plugins that are either out of date or will not copy over the required content I'd need.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,

Mark

Comment: If I were you I'd try the multisite duplicator anyway. Nothing you've mentioned (posts, ACF fields - which are just post meta) has changed in WordPress for a while as far as I know.

Comment: Or if you haven't already, I'd post in [the plugin's support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/multisite-post-duplicator/) (or [GitHub issues](https://github.com/magicstickuk/multisite-post-duplicator/issues)) and ask the author there about updates or of they know of anything that won't work.

Comment: (There are no substantial forks in the [GitHub network graph](https://github.com/magicstickuk/multisite-post-duplicator/network), which either means there's no bugs that other people have needed to fix, or no-one's using it anymore.)